# SQl query through another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
Programme                     Student                      Grade
Pid (pk)                      StudentID(pk)                ModuleID(cpk)     
                              ProgrammeID(fk)              StudentID(cpk)
                                                           Gradepercent
```

I have three tables, a programme table, grade table and student table.I am trying to get the average percentage grade for each programme. The problem is that the grade table is not linked to the Programme table, only connected by the student table. The primary key is programmeid for the programme table(fk in student table) and studentid in the student table and a composite pk is used in  the grade table of moduleid/studentid to identify the grade. (module a fourth table in the database containg moduleid which is not relevant)

How do i go about making a query to get the av grade for a programme?  I am assuming there is a way to do it without using the student table, something along the lines of

```
SELECT AVG(Gradepercent) from grade AND group by ProgrammeID from programme
```

(synthax error) but would prefer a query which uses the student table to access the information in the grades table through their relationships.

Any ideas on how to go about this?? I understand that this is not very clear but if someone could point me in the right direction it would help a lot.

(I have an ERD which would make this post a lot clearer but for some reason i am not allowed post it despite having 10 reputation).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Student.ProgrammeID, AVG(Grade.GradePercent)
FROM Student
INNER JOIN Grade ON Student.StudentID = Grade.StudentID
GROUP BY Student.ProgrammeID
```

Comment: Excellent; I'm glad it worked! Your original question asked if you could skip the `Student` table for this, but you can't because `Student` is what ties `Programme` to `Grade`. Does that make sense to you? I hope so; it's an important concept. If it doesn't make sense right now don't panic - it'll become clear as you work through other queries :)